# phpmyadmin (wamp) not working anymore

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-connection, wamp

I've played a little with php and data bases a few weeks ago and it worked perfectly. Now, when I tested the same thing again, I realized that it is not runnable anymore. More exactly, when I have to access the data base, I get the following type of notice:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in E:\wamp\www\test\login.php on line 18
```

When I try to open `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` I get a blank screen
Please give me the possible explanations

Comment: I found out what had happenned. I opened mysql.log where it was written that host.MYD is missing. It had somehow been deleted as a result of an antivirus scan. When I repaired this, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another application using port 3306, another MySQL running perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The Possible explanation is

1. i suspect you have installed and uninstalled wamp? in that case you need to check you driver/etc/.hosts file under system32 ("Google it for exact path") :) and you have to make sure there exist only one value for

   127.0.0.1 localhost
2. As it said above you need to check your running port has already used by another instance by checking

   netstat -a and see if 3306 is Listening
3. Check on windows services that MySQL ,Apache are running or able to run automatically or manually from the service
4. suggest uninstall properly ==> delete all inside the wamp folder except www --takecare